# grep *stringA*[number]

Tags: grep

I was wondering how can I grep an expression of the type

```
*stringA*[number]
```

In other words, I want to target lines that have the following pattern:

```
 anything + stringA + anything + [number]
```

For example these strings would match:

```
stringA[3]
this is a test stringA because_[4]
nothing really stringA[5]
```

these strings would not match:

```
stringA
something else [7]
```

How can I do this with grep? (or grep -e)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
grep 'stringA.*\[[[:digit:]]\]'
```

`.*` matches any character 0 or more times. `\[` and `\]` escape their respective characters, which otherwise have special meaning. `[:digit:]` (usually) expands to `0123456789`.

Comment: Thanks Chris, why do I need three square brackets? (in your explanation you describe two levels of bracketing: `\[  \]` and `[:digit:]`

Comment: @intrpc Firstly, the literal `[`. Then, `[` (character class), which matches any character contained. Then, `[:digit:]`, which expands to a list of digits. Then, the reverse.